# Не открывается сертификат в Мac OS

Tags: macos, safari, x509certificate, sha256

Добрый день.

Для корпоративного сайта был создан сертификат с sha256 и ключом в 4 Кб, с помощью ЦР на windows. Браузеры на него ругались, но позволяли зайти на сайт. Но Safari вообще не позволяет зайти на сайт, даже его не открывает, на мобильной версии приложение вообще падает, в логах ошибка:

> Exeption Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUG)
>
> Exeption Sybtype: EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN at 0x00000012

В программе Keychain Access этот сертификат даже не открывается и ошибок не выдает.

Каким образом можно проверить в чем ошибка сертификата (если даже его прочитать в MAC OS не получается)? В Windows сертификат читается.

Comment: При создании сертификата с помощью OpenSSL проблем не возникает. Но пытаюсь понять почему не работает при создании средствами ЦР.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем выяснилось, что в создаваемом сертификате некоторые поля (ОГРН и ИНН) были с типом NUMERIC STRING. OpenSSL выпускает поля в другой кодировке.
Похоже, что Safari не очень дружит с этим типом данных. Но это ещё предстоит проверить, когда я пойму как сделать данный в сертификате выпущенном OpenSSL - NUMERIC STRING.

Считаю вопрос закрытым.